# Select statement to get a treelike structure in a list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql table with the following entries:

```
ID, Name, ParentID   
1,  A,  null
2,  B,  null
3,  C,  1
4,  D,  null
5,  E,  1
```

I want to get a list sorted by name, but the subs should be after the parent

```
Expected result: A, C, E, B, D
```

How can I solve this with SQL query? A groupby on parentID does not solve the problem as then, I get (C, E), (A, B, D)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, MSAccess?

Comment: Oracle and I am also using LINQ.

Comment: This is typically solved with a Recursive Query, which in SQL Server is known as a CTE (Common Table Expression).  I don't know the Oracle equivilent.

Comment: How many levels will exist? can you tell your expected output if you also have 6-F-5, 7-G-3 ? (i.e. F child to E and G child to C, which both are roots under A)...

Answer (score 0):

I was once able to achieve something similar by following query in C#:
(it will work in SQL server at least)

```
select t.animalid as animalid,
 t.sireid as S,
 t.damid as D, 

 t1.damid as SD,
 t2.sireid as DS,
 t2.damid as DD,
 t3.sireid as SSS,
 t3.damid as SSD
 from PedigreeData t

 left join PedigreeData t1 on t1.animalidt.sireid
 left join PedigreeData t2 on t2.animalidt.damid
 left join PedigreeData t3 on t1.sireidt3.animalid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one level of parent/child you can simply use:

```
SELECT  NVL(ParentID, ID) AS ParentID,  
        LISTAGG(Name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS Members
FROM    T
GROUP BY NVL(ParentID, ID);
```

This gives:

```
PARENTID    MEMBERS
---------------------
1           A, C, E
2           B
4           D
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1e48/1)**

Otherwise you will need to use recursion to get the base ID for each Member (i.e. if you have a 6th entity with a parentID = 5):

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  CONNECT_BY_ROOT ID AS ID, 
            Name, 
            LEVEL As LVL,
            MAX(LEVEL) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS MaxLevel
    FROM    T
    CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ParentID
)
SELECT  ID, 
        LISTAGG(Name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS Members
FROM    CTE
WHERE   LVL = MaxLevel
GROUP BY ID;
```

Which gives:

```
ID  MEMBERS
1   A, C, E, F
2   B
4   D
```

With the first query the result would be:

```
ID  MEMBERS
1   A, C, E
2   B
4   D
5   F
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/824f7/1)**

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle this variant works:

```
select 
  listagg(Name, ',') 
    within group (order by rn)         -- Collect values as arranged
                                       -- in previous query 
from (
  select
    rownum rn,                         -- Collect order of rows 
    Name
  from t
  start with ParentID is null
  connect by prior ID = ParentID       -- Get hierarchy by ParentID
  order siblings by Name               -- Arrange nodes on each level by Name   
)
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71fdb/1)